# Wordpress: store year and month in variable

Tags: wordpress, variables, date

On a specific archive page on a Wordpress site, I have the url:

```
http://fruitpage/2013/04/
```

The year and the month numbers tells Wordpress which posts to show (posts from april 2013). Is there a way to store 2013 in one variable and 04 in another, using Wordpress functionality?

The goal is to be able to echo out the year and month that is in the url, for example:

```
echo $urlYear; //echoes out 2013 that is found in the url
echo $urlMonth; //echoes out 04 that is found in the url
```

Comment: "Store in a variable" in what context? Where?

Comment: I want to be able to echo out $year and $month, resulting in the values that are in the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In archive page, you simple call `the_date()` function **within the post loop**

```
$year = the_date('Y');

$month = the_date('m');
```

try `get_the_time()` also

Comment: are you sure it can be used in archive.php page?

Comment: It didn't work with the_date, but get_the_time made the trick! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use these

```
<?php echo get_the_date('M'); ?> for month
<?php echo get_the_date('Y'); ?> for year
```

Comment: Why should the OP "just use this"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.